# jQuery - Calculate the value by multiplying it by the checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cakephp-3.0

I need to calculate the value `total`, which is a product of initial value (let's say 10) and the factors A, B, C and D, which are equal to, let's say 2, 3, 4 and 5.

The combination of factors should be selected by user via checking the corresponding boxes. The problem is that I need to repeat this many times independently in a form and the solution below (for two of these sections) does not separate this process correctly. If these were text values, I would do e.g.  `var $text = $(".result", $section);`

Basically, I do not understand how to relate numerical variable to these sections. Also, it would be great to have this initial value (10) in the `Result` field even if none of the boxes are checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $(".factor-checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var $section = $(this).closest(".section");
        var total = 10;
        $(".factor-checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            total *= parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        
            $('.result').val(total);
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text" class="result"></label>
    
</div>

<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text" class="result"></label>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the rows to be independent:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $(".factor-checkbox").click(function(event) {
        var $section = $(this).closest(".section"),
            initial = parseInt($section.find('.result').data('initial')),
            total = initial;
        $section.find("input:checked").each(function() {
            total *= parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $section.find('.result').val(total === initial ? initial : total);
        
    });
    // getting the total values
    $(".res_button").click(function() {
        var $section = $(this).closest(".section");
        var total = $section.find('.result').val();
        console.log(total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text" data-initial="10" value="10" class="result"></label>
    
    <label><button class="res_button">Result 1 line</button></label>
</div>

<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text" data-initial="20" value="20" class="result"></label>

    <label><button class="res_button">Result 2 line</button></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Is there any way to have 10 in the Result field from the very beginning?

Comment: Yes, you can put it there as initial value by adding `value` attribute to the `.result` input like `value="10"`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Can I read the initial value of total from this attribute? Now it always takes 10 for all entries.

Comment: @Vincent Vega Sure, you can read the value of that attribute at any moment. I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that it does not work if initial values in the html above are, e.g.: value="10" and value="20"

Comment: I think I got it. The problem is that "10" was hard coded. Instead, you need to keep initial values in an additional attribute 'data-initial' and if there are no checkboxes checked, then set the field to its initial value. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $(".factor-checkbox").click(function() {
       var $section= $(this).closest(".section")
        var total = 10;
        $section.find(".factor-checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            total *= parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $section.find(".result").val(total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text" value="10" class="result"></label>
    
</div>

<div class="section">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="A" value="2" class="factor-checkbox">A</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="B" value="3" class="factor-checkbox">B</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="C" value="4" class="factor-checkbox">C</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="D" value="5" class="factor-checkbox">D</label>

    <label>Result <input type="text" value="10" class="result"></label>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick suggestion, but the second Result in your version is influenced by the first one. If I check A in the first raw, I will get 20, in the second - 40.